# How to detect the internal server error (500) in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'll only share the most important piece of code

```
$product = DB::table('products')->where('id','=',$pid)->get();
//the above code makes no errors
if ($product[0]::sale == '1') // this line of code makes error
        {
            //$cost+=($product[0]->price - ($product[0]->discount*$product[0]->price/100));
        }
        else
        {
            //$cost+=$product[0]->price;
        }
```

it's clear this line `if ($product[0]::sale == '1')` makes error

however I couldn't catch it - when I send the request - I only receive 500 (Internal server error) - I event can't catch the error

-- updates

return $product // makes error

return var_dump($product);

returning this

```
object(stdClass)#234 (23) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(16) "oihoh jewioh 234"
  ["id"]=>
  string(9) "hew7h23iu"
  ["desciption"]=>
  string(162) "ewhniuhewch2398h9h32
32dh2398dh23dh3
d2h3d8h238dh2389hd98
3d2hd8932hd8h23329dj892
j9hd2dh8723gd7g32d
23dh9832hd8h2389dh9h239dh239
23d8h3289dh3298d9h32dh329h"
  ["sizes"]=>
  string(4) "M,XL"
  ["colors"]=>
  string(14) "#12f,#caf,#afa"
  ["amount"]=>
  int(12)
  ["category"]=>
  string(5) "Women"
  ["scategory"]=>
  string(5) "Lambs"
  ["featured"]=>
  int(1)
  ["minfo"]=>
  string(23) "sia:deuw,on:iej,od:jdiw"
  ["images"]=>
  string(288) "snoicds,nconew,ncoiwenioew,http://www.ridgetopvirtualsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/product-that-sells-4-ridgetopvirtualsolutions.jpg*snoicdse,nconew,ncoiwenioew,http://www.ridgetopvirtualsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/product-that-sells-4-ridgetopvirtualsolutions.jpg"
  ["video"]=>
  NULL
  ["fimage"]=>
  string(143) "snoicds,nconew,ncoiwenioew,http://www.ridgetopvirtualsolutions.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/product-that-sells-4-ridgetopvirtualsolutions.jpg"
  ["sale"]=>
  int(0)
  ["price"]=>
  float(26.5)
  ["sold"]=>
  int(32)
  ["views"]=>
  int(14)
  ["likes"]=>
  int(24)
  ["discount"]=>
  NULL
  ["dexpire"]=>
  NULL
  ["created_at"]=>
  NULL
  ["updated_at"]=>
  NULL
  ["avgreview"]=>
  float(3.4)
}
```

Comment: Please check the [`debug` configuration option](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#configuration).

Comment: @JitendraSoftgrid - both ($product[0]->sale == '1' and $product[0]::sale == '1') makes the same error

Comment: yes - it returns this : object(stdClass)#234 (23) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(16) "oihoh jewioh 234" .. etc
}

Comment: return var_dump($product->sale); -> output : int(0)

Answer (score 1):

Working with the query builder, you shouldn't receive that type of error. It's because you're treating it as an array. We've all done that.

The good news is, it's much better than that! Use:

```
$product = DB::table('products')->find($pid);
```

Then use the code below to check if a product exists.

```
if ( $product ) { ... }
```

Comment: and then -> if ($product->sale == '1') , still makes 500 error

Comment: Is the sale field a Boolean?

Comment: whatever - It is not the problem- because $product->sale itself makes error , return $product->sale makes error;

Comment: return $product -> is returning object(stdClass)#234 (23) { ["title"]=> string(16) "oihoh jewioh 234" .. etc }

Comment: Do you have debug set as true in your .env file? It should be showing you a more descriptive error. My guess is that no product is found with that ID. This would be throwing a 'getting property of non-object' error.

Comment: I also updated the code for a more direct, simple, and fast approach.

Comment: No - it's 100% exist
APP_DEBUG=true in .env file

Comment: Use `dd( $product );` instead of returning it. Does it have a `sale` field?

Comment: Can you put that dump in your question so I can see it?

Comment: Just so you know, a die and dump, or `dd()` is a bit cleaner. Also, your description field is misspelled. Try setting a value in the DB for the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields.

Comment: I assume Laravel has some bugs or lacks in declaring what's the error I have

Comment: It&#39;s highly unlikely that something this small would make an error like this that has never been caught. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I see you far away from the exact problem we're talking about

Comment: If you don't know the solution, how would you know I'm far away? If you're not going to work with me, why should I work with you? Remember that I'm trying to help.